# Twitter's Bootstrap collapse with manual control - div is not hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use [Twitter's Bootstrap collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) **inside** of each collapsible element. But it doesn't work as I expect - see [the demo](http://jsbin.com/exomaw/edit#preview):

1. when *Search* button is pressed it is OK, since manually controlled via javascript:

   $("#myform").collapse('hide'); 
   $("#search-results").collapse('show');
2. when link *show search form* is clicked, I expect `myform` to be shown, but `search-results` to be hidden, but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You Can add this code to your **ready** function

```
 $("a").click(function(){
    $("#myform").collapse('show');
      $("#search-results").collapse('hide');
  });
```

Here is a working example : http://jsbin.com/upavon/1/edit

Thanks